# json child append to the corresponding parent

Tags: php

[image]i am trying to append the child to the corresponding parent in JSON...
Below is my code:
I have one json in $json1 and multiple json in $json2. 
$json1 and $json2 -https://pastebin.com/DTn5EPxq

```
       <?php

        $djson1 = json_decode($json1);
        $djson2 = json_decode($json2, true);
        $result['id'] = $djson1->{'id'};
        $result['name'] = $djson1->{'name'};
        $result['tooltip'] = $djson1->{'tooltip'};
        $result['color'] = $djson1->{'color'};
        foreach ($djson1->{'children'} as $key => $value) {
            $result['children'][$key]['name'] = $value->{'name'};
                $result['children'][$key]['parent'] = $value->{'parent'};
            $result['children'][$key]['tooltip'] = $value->{'tooltip'};
            $result['children'][$key]['color'] = $value->{'color'};
        }
        foreach ($djson2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value2['name'] == $result['children'][$key2]['name']) {
                foreach ($value2['children'] as $key3 => $value3) {
            $result['children'][$key2]['children']
            [$key3]['name'] = $value3['name'];
            $result['children'][$key2]['children']
            [$key3]['parent'] = $value3['parent'];
            $result['children'][$key2]['children']
            [$key3]['tooltip'] = $value3['tooltip'];
            $result['children'][$key2]['children']
            [$key3]['color'] = $value3['color'];
                }
            }
        }


        //var_dump($result);
        //var_dump(json_encode($result));

        ?>


        <?php echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>
```

i am getting Undefined offset error in  this line:

```
        if($value2['name'] == $result['children'][$key2]['name']) {
```

this code works well ,when i am using few json in $json2 ..shows error only when using bulk of json in $json2..how should i solve this issue???

Comment: because   $result['children'][2]['name'] don't have key 2 . it have only 0 and 1 so it's undefined index

Comment: thanks for your response...but when i echo it like this if($result['children'][$key2]['name']!==''){
  echo $result['children'][$key2]['name'];
  
 }...it shows the childrens in $json1

Comment: it will show only for 0 and 1 key for 2 it will not show  just do something like this you will know the error foreach ($djson2 as $key2 => $value2) {
  
     echo $result['children'][$key2]['name']." key = $key2<br> ";  .... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$result['children'][2]['name']` don't have key 2 . it have only 0 and 1 so it's undefined index

**$result array is**

```
        $result = Array ( [id] => 1 
            [name] => à®•à¯à®´à¯‚à®‰ 
            [tooltip] => [color] => 
            [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => à®•à¯‚à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà®®à¯ [parent] => 1 [tooltip] => [color] => #FF0000 ) 
                                  [1] => Array ( [name] => [parent] => 1 [tooltip] => [color] => #FFFFCC )
                                )
            )
```

**Update 1:**

Use `array_column` to get all children name and use `array_search`  if it's match return it will return the key . so using that key you can push the array like this

```
$new_array = array_column($result['children'],'name');

    foreach ($djson2 as $key2 => $value2) {

        if($new_key = array_search($value2['name'],$new_array)) 
        {
            foreach ($value2['children'] as $key3 => $value3) 
            {
                $result['children'][$new_key]['children'][$key3]['name'] = $value3['name'];
                $result['children'][$new_key]['children'][$key3]['parent'] = $value3['parent'];
                $result['children'][$new_key]['children'][$key3]['tooltip'] = $value3['tooltip'];
                $result['children'][$new_key]['children'][$key3]['color'] = $value3['color'];
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 2:**

The problem is our `$json1 name is "கூட்டம் "` have space at end but       `$json2 name is "கூட்டம்"` that's why it's not go inside the if condition just user `array_map` to trim the space like this .

```
        $array1 = array_column($result['children'],'name');
       $new_array = array_map('trim',$array1);

        foreach ($djson2 as $key2 => $value2) {

            $true_or_false_key = array_search($value2['name'],$new_array);


            if($true_or_false_key !== false)
            {
                foreach ($value2['children'] as $key3 => $value3)
                {
                    $result['children'][ $true_or_false_key]['children'][$key3]['name'] = $value3['name'];
                    $result['children'][ $true_or_false_key]['children'][$key3]['parent'] = $value3['parent'];
                    $result['children'][ $true_or_false_key]['children'][$key3]['tooltip'] = $value3['tooltip'];
                    $result['children'][ $true_or_false_key]['children'][$key3]['color'] = $value3['color'];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ,.the result is $json1 data.    
               {"id":"1","name":"குழூஉ","tooltip":" ","color":" ","children":[{"name":"கூட்டம் ","parent":"1","tooltip":" ","color":"#FF0000 "},{"name":" ","parent":"1","tooltip":" ","color":"\t#FFFFCC"}]}....anyway thanks...i am trying...

Comment: let me say the result

Comment: i used like this -https://pastebin.com/0Hb5s55b ...and the output is {"id":"1","name":"குழூஉ","tooltip":" ","color":" ","children":[{"name":"கூட்டம் ","parent":"1","tooltip":" ","color":"#FF0000 "},{"name":" ","parent":"1","tooltip":" ","color":"\t#FFFFCC"}]}..plz correct me..if i am wrong

Comment: yeah your correct did you get desired result ? @prog

Comment: no...the result is $json1 data...(i.e){"id":"1","name":"குழூஉ","tooltip":" ","color":" ","children":[{"name":"கூட்டம் ","parent":"1","tooltip":" ","color":"#FF0000 "},{"name":" ","parent":"1","tooltip":" ","color":"\t#FFFFCC"}]}

Comment: yeah it's not go inside the if condition . wait a minute . i will check and update you asap. @prog

Comment: problem identified . the problem is our $json1 name is "கூட்டம் "  have space at end but $json2 name is "கூட்டம்" don't have space that's why it's not go inside the if condition  . @prog

Comment: can you check my update2 . it's works perfectly i tested too @prog

Comment: glad to help you @prog

Comment: i have one doubt...for children's children name i have to use  $array= array_column($result['children']['children'],'name');...am i rite?

Comment: YES your right . array_column is fetch the specific column from given array .@prog

Comment: getting undefined index in this line itself ..foreach ($djson1->{'children'}{'children'} as $key => $value)...can you plz tell me..how should i use children's children here..-https://pastebin.com/qmeGVBbp...you can see there is no child from the word  திரள் in the updated question

Comment: it's totally new question . don't update old question . create new question with detailed description people will help you and i too . @prog